# Is it ok to use or with if in this case

Tags: conjunctions, interrogatives

I was writing an essay, and I came upon some confusing situation. Is it ok to say:

> It never said if it used several metals of same kind, or used just one
>   big metal.

I thought word if in this case can be used with or only if used with not like this:

> It never said if it used several metals of same kind or not.

So is it grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable colloquially, but I would avoid using *if* for *whether* in any moderately formal context -- schoolwork, for instance, or professional writing.

Incidentally, we do not use *metals* for *pieces* or *components* of metal. *Metal* is a ordinarily a mass/non-count noun; we use the plural, *metals*, only when we need to distinguish different sorts of metal: "Steel, brass, and aluminum are all metals." What you probably mean is this:

> It never said whether the pieces were made of different metals or were all of the same metal.

Comment: We don't know what was meant under "*same kind*" (it ought to be "**the** same kind", BTW).  It could be "several rare-earth metals" or "several highly active metals".  Of course, "big metal" is a strange word combination...

Comment: @VictorBazarov Yes; I'm not at all sure that the first sentence isn't intended to distinguish several metal components from a single metal casting.

Comment: It should probably be a separate question, to prevent topic drift.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, grammatically both are OK.

However, the latter has a different meaning.  Reading that sentence leaves us wondering what the alternatives (to using several metals of some kind) might have been.  One metal?  No metals?  Several kinds of wood?  Several plastics?..

An "*if*" used like this is a stand-in for "whether", which also can be used with 'or' and without it.